# Store and re-use widgets in dictionary/ list

Tags: python, tkinter

so i have to do a snake using tkinter and i'm asked to either store the widget in a dictionary or a list.

the code i was given to work with is :

```
tk_frame['score'] = Frame(fen)
tk_frame['score'].pack()

tk_frame['jeu']= Frame(fen)
tk_frame['jeu'].pack()

tk_frame['gestion']= Frame(fen)
tk_frame['gestion'].pack()
```

The computer asked what "tk_frame was" so i created a dictionary :

```
tk_frame = {'score' : Frame(fen), 'jeu' : Frame(fen), 'gestion' : Frame(fen)}
```

but then i have to call these keys as arguments in other functions and i don't know how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you want call 'score', do:

```
tk_frame['score'].pack()
```

assuming you want to pack these widgets.

The same principle applies for the other keys